# SSRS - row height not increasing after excel import

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, export-to-excel

I have an SSRS report with 5 Tablix data regions. All but first tablix, have "Notes" column which can have huge amounts of text in it. I have set CanGrow properties of these cells to be "True".

But when I export the report to an excel file, row size has not increased to show full contents of Notes. I see that, it works perfectly when I keep only one Tablix. It fails only when I have more than one Tablix.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSRS won't expand the row height when exported to Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25443794/ssrs-wont-expand-the-row-height-when-exported-to-excel)

Answer (score 0):

When have multiple tablix in your report, after you exporting into excel, it will automatically keep the tablix original position and size to other tablixs. So it may not change the row height. I think this issue is more related to Excel cell setting.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255234.aspx