# How can we get data to not cut off in Excel when exported from a SSRS Report?

Tags: reporting-services, export-to-excel

I am seeing an issue with exporting data from a report (SSRS) to MS Excel. The issue is that the exported data in Excel appears to get cut off within the rows. Please see the highlighted text in red.

[image]

Is there a setting or configuration in SSRS that needs to be set to ensure that the exported data is cleanly formatted in Excel? I set the 'Allow height to increase' to True, however it did not help. I also set 'CanGrow' to True but this did not help as well.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This appears to be an issue in SSRS since forever. [See the comments on this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31616302/3585500)